# How to change the existing jquery and html logic with react code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an existing application, using jquery and html.
- One functionality is to open a collapse on button click with all data and able to close again. 
- Now i need to replace this jquery and html using react code?

Can i use create-react-app or how to achieve it?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
    <button id="rejectbtn">reject</button>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have the table like the upper one, where there is a reject button.Now on click of this reject button, one collapse is opening which is a form containing all the row data.
This collapse is made using HTML and jquery.
I want to replace this with react code.

Comment: This question is too broad, if you narrow down the question to some piece of code you want to change we could provide help, otherwise the question would be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a react UI library, one example is google'sReact Material UI.
For your case I think Modal component will do 
https://material-ui.com/utils/modal/

Answer (score 0):

With the information given, could make out that you need something like an accordion, which is easily achievable through jquery. What is that you are looking by converting this implementation to react?

However, if you need to convert this to a react component, you need to understand JSX through which you can create the markup, then attach events eventually to achieve the desired result.

For more information please refer: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html